Double vanity, one sink drains slowly
Pics show waste and vents above floor and below. The drain on the right connects to the main waste pipe. (It’s near enough that it doesn’t need a separate vent.) The one on the left has a vent with a Studor Air Admittance Valve in the unfinished attic.
The one on the left usually drains slightly slowly - but sometimes it drains quickly. I’m not sure what determines the difference. Perhaps the Studor sticks?
Does the piping look correct?



how does the STUDOR works

AAVs do not help draining, they only prevent siphoning, you have a tee installed with the branch facing up, I don''t think that's allowed  and the two 45s are questionable too.

I'm confused. Why does your vent come in below the drain? Why haven't you simply boxed the drain for the right sink into the existing vent stack? (And why haven't you put the vent through the roof?)

Tx Jasen, The tee and two 45s are BELOW the vanity installation.  I think the Tee branch is oriented correctly.  Let me know if I'm missing something.

Tx Isherwood,  I may be the one who is confused.  The vent stack is distant  - the vertical PVC in the image is for the AAV.  Its purpose is to break syphon for the left sink. The AAV needs to be located above the sink drains and can't be enclosed in the wall.  So I ran it into the attic, where it's "nominally" accessible. It could have penetrated the roof and become a conventional vent, but I didn't want to disrupt the roofing material. (The right sink is almost directly above the main drain, short distance - hence no separate vent. It works well consistently, quick to drain and no gurgle).

Isherwood, I thought (perhaps mistakenly) that the connection below the drain connector would be adequate to break any syphon.  It could have tied in above the drain connector.  Could this cause problems?  My theory is still that the Studor valve sometimes sticks - failing to break syphon - and sometimes functions properly so the left drain works all the time, but sometimes is slightly slower than on the right.  Just a theory, looking for some experienced perspective on this.

Traveler, here's a link to the manufacturer's page https://ipsplumbingproducts.com/brands/studor/frequently-asked-questions-studor/#:~:text=The%20Studor%20Air%20Admittance%20Valve%20(AAV)%20is%20a%20one%2D,from%20escaping%20into%20the%20valve.

As an aside, the arm from the left vent to the drain needs to be sloped towards the drain.  Maybe it's the photo but it seems to be sloped the other way or horizontal.  If you move it higher per the answer, it still needs to be sloped so water doesn't collect in it.

Updated Answer:
If you have access to the venting for the left sink and can revise it so that the vent connects above the fixture drain, then you can wet vent the right sink through the left sink's drainage as in the sketch below. This would be a better solution.

Original Answer:
Both sinks are piped in a manner that would not pass a plumbing code. The vent connection on the left sink must be above, not below the tee for the fixture drain. The sink on the right must be vented, its proximity to the 'main waste pipe' means nothing.
It looks like you installed tees in the wall to poke out for the sink's fixture drains, the correct way would have been to extend the upper end of each tee up into the attic and connect them to an existing vent, or add a new vent, or lastly use an air admittance valve.
Here's what it should have looked like:

The simplest (and likely the best) way to correct this installation would be to add the vents as per the above. This would involve opening up the walls, or at least making holes in the walls so that you can drill through the horizontal framing.
Another option, that would not require opening walls, assuming that the piping below is accessible, would be to reconfigure the piping so that both sinks drain to a common p-trap located below. This p-trap could be vented by repurposing the existing left sink's drain. You would be required to drill through the floor and the bottom of the cabinet on the left side to connect the left sink. You should be able to reuse the drain for the right sink. This assumes that your local code allows for common trapping of two similar single-compartment fixtures located in the same room and that the developed length of each sink's fixture drain does not exceed 4 feet (or whatever length your code limits it to).
Here is a sketch of this arrangement. The blue lines are the existing piping, the red lines are the changes, and the yellow highlighted line is the developed length of the right sink.


Wow.  You set the gold standard for a thoughtful, critical, but helpful response.  And you provided a ton of useful info.  I appreciate that you educated, rather than slammed, me.  Nicely done!!

Considering only the left sink for a moment.  Could I use the P-trap under the sink if I reroute the vertical vent to come in above the trap weir?  I can access from the back side and move the horizontal leg of what should have been a vent to be ABOVE the trap water level.  For that one sink, is that a viable option?

As for the Right sink, the Developed Length from the (under sink) P trap to the main stack drain is less than 4 feet.  Is that a viable configuration?

Given your comment that you can access the left sink's venting, I've updated my answer. Regarding the developed length: it is measured from the sink connection to the p-trap connection.

Maybe I'm seeing the diagrams incorrectly but is the proposal to put the trap below the floor?  Perhaps in the wall of the floor below?  How will it be serviced/snaked?

@jay613, Yes, I'm proposing that the p-trap be installed below the floor, in what looks like an accessible crawl space. Note that p-traps are installed below concrete slab-on-grade all the time for bathtubs, showers, floor drains, etc.

They are installed that way out of necessity and snaking them is royally painful compared to one under a sink, which you don't have to snake at all because you can just remove it.  But anyway .. you are right about the crawl space, I didn't see that so it's a pretty good idea.

@pdd Again, thanks for the really helpful advice!  Can I go one step further by putting sub-floor traps on BOTH sinks, with a sloping wet drain between?  That would avoid opening the walls at all.  The vents would be above the traps, with less than 4' developed length from each sink to trap.  Workable?

@pdd In the above scenario (my prev comment with two underfloor traps), a horizontal leg of vent on the left side would NOT be above the sink flood level. Is that a deal breaker?  The physics suggests that it might well be, but I thought I should ask. Thanks again.

The reason you do not offset a vent horizontally until 6" above the fixture's flood-level rim is that if the drain gets plugged you want the fixture to overflow before the vent fills with water/solids. If the vent receives water/solids, over time the vent could become restricted due to a buildup. In your scenario, the likelihood of your vent becoming plugged would be small.
